# How many servers can connect to a SAS RAID without a SAS switch?

Tags: switch, sas, raid

If we buy a

- Promise **VTrak E610sD SAS Raid** shelf
- and daisy-chain Promise **VTrak J610sD SAS JBOD** shelves to the Raid shelf

How many Linux servers with SAS HBA cards can get access to this setup without a SAS switch?

Can we setup 2 SAS HBA cards per Linux server for path redundancy?

The manual is [here](http://www.promise.com/media_bank/Download%20Bank/Manual/VTrak_E-Class_PM_v3.1.pdf). The compatibility sheet is [here](http://www.promise.com/media_bank/Download%20Bank/Compatibility/E-Class_Compatibility_List_SR2.6.pdf).

Comment: Great looks like it's going to work. Here is the product manual http://www.promise.com/media_bank/Download%20Bank/Manual/VTrak_E-Class_PM_v3.2.pdf (page 35 shows the topology that we would want). There maybe even a possibility to connect more than 2 Linux servers (up to 6) if we get a fanout cable (1-4x-SFF-8088 to 4-1x-SFF-8088).

Comment: The compatibility sheet has a note saying "Redundant SAS dual controller not supported" for SuSE. If that applies to all Linux disrtos then we may be out of luck for setting a redundant path system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading the [spec sheets](http://www.promise.com/support/download_file.aspx?rsn=141&m=93&region=en-global) right, you can connect up to 4 initiators (Linux servers in your case) to that device. The fact that it supports "LUN Masking" is a dead give-away that it's intended to be used with multiple servers. If you want 2 SAS HBAs per server, each HBA will consume a slot, so only two servers may be attached to this array.

I'm not sure how smart the LUN Masking is. You may need to be sure you add both HBAs to the allowed list on each LUN to ensure that full redundancy is possible.